# IMG SRC ID, set from a link

Tags: html, image, href

I am trying to create a simple link that will allow me to change an image on my page.  I've given the image an id:

img src="myImage.png" id="display"/

How would you change this image using a?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use jQuery and add an event listener to the `<a/>`. It would go something like this:

```
/*
 * Note that I add an ID to the <a/> tag selector
 * as we don't want to listen to ALL <a/> tags
 * and only a specific one. Make sure to add an ID to you <a/>
 */
$('a#click-to-change-img').on('click',function(evt){
    $('#display').attr('src','/assets/img/new-image-file.png');
});
```

You could also do inline JavaScript (which I personally dislike)

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('display').src='/assets/img/new-image-file.png';return false;">
    Click Me
</a>
```

In both cases, we wait for the  tag to be clicked. When it is, we then run a function which will locate the  tag with the "id" of "display" and change the value of its "src" attribute